# How to write if statement comparing numbers that creates objects conditionally in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm working with QML and Python3.6 + PySide2 and I'm trying to write script in QML that takes two integers from a connection in python and compares them to decide what image background to use for the window.

There are a few things I'm struggling with. First, I am unsure how to compare my numeric (sunset and sunrise) variables. Second, I don't know how to write an if statement-esque part that produces a background image conditionally. Third, I don't think it's best to do this under Connections, and maybe even in my QML, but I'm not sure how to move my variables somewhere else.

I really appreciate any pointers or help!!

The data I'm drawing from looks like this: 
"sunrise":1592565499,"sunset":1592617094

The QML pseudo-ish code:

```
Connections {
        target: weather
        function onDataChanged(){
            if(!weather.hasError()){
                var sunrise = weather.data['dt']['sunrise']
                var sunset = weather.data['dt']['sunset']
                if (sunrise <= sunset)
                    Image {
                      source: "night.png"}
                else 
                    Image {
                      course: "day.png"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create QML-items from if-statements like that (neither from `State`'s). You can call `Qt.createComponent` if you like, however, it is rather overkill in this example. You should directly set the `source` property of your image:

```
Image {
   id: image_tod
}

Connections {
   target: weather
   function onDataChanged(){
      if(!weather.hasError()){
         var sunrise = weather.data['dt']['sunrise']
         var sunset = weather.data['dt']['sunset']
         if (sunrise <= sunset)
            image_tod.source = "night.png"
         else 
               image_tod.source = "day.png"
      }
   }
}
```

Looking at the code, you might actually be able to bind it directly to the `source` property (not sure what your model exactly looks like):

```
 Image {
     source: {
         if(weather.data['dt']['sunrise'] <= weather.data['dt']['sunset'])
             return "night.png"
         else
             return "day.png"
     }
 }
```

This works because when compiling the QML, the engine creates a dependency from every referenced variable (`weather` and `data` in this case), and re-evaluates the whole binding if any of them signals a change. To make fully use of this, you should also expose `hasError` as a property rather than a function (and emit whenever it changes).

---

Follow-up update

Yes, you can make it as wild as you want. I think you mean this:

```
 Image {
     source: {
         if(weather.data['dt']['sunrise'] <= weather.data['dt']['sunset'])
             return "night.png"
         else if(weather.data['dt']['sunrise'] > weather.data['dt']['sunset'])
             return "day.png"
         else
             return "" //means no image
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This answer was really helpful, I had no clue you could even use "if" in QML. Could I ask if there was a way to set a default image and override it with "day" or "night" once the if statement runs?

Comment: The if-statement is always run! you can add another if-statement for the error and return the default there

Comment: Hi! I hope you dont mind me following up! Might I ask if there's a way to add a three condition "if" statement? ie. something like this: if (time >= sunset) or (time <= sunrise), else (time = sunrise)

Comment: @sun (btw, what a funny name for this question ;-) ), I edited my question with another else-if-statement

Comment: loL yes it is quite fitting. Thank you so much!! I wasn't able to find the syntax in my searches so this helps a lot!!

Comment: @sun, btw another option is to set `visible: !weather.inError` (given you add the property) to hide the image